# AttributeError: 'C' object attribute 'y' is read-only when using slots

Tags: python-3.x

I'm playing a bit with slots and I've come across one thing. I have the following code

```
class C(object):
    __slots__ = ('x',)
    def __init__(self, v):
        self.x = v
    y = 123

c = C(5)
c.y = 12
```

When I run the code I get the following error

```
AttributeError: 'C' object attribute 'y' is read-only
```

I'm not sure if my explanation for this behavior is correct:
since 'y' is not a valid instance variable (only 'x' is valid -> slots), the class dictionary is searched for the key 'y' (lookup chain). Since it has type 'mappingproxy' it is unchangeable and the value can not be set.
Without using slots the expression `c.y = 12` causes an entry in the object's dictionary, which is why I don't get the error without using slots.

Answer (score 0):

There is no class dictionary when you use slots. The allowed properties are implemented via descriptors (as described in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#slots)). Furthermore, you defined `y` as a *class attribute*, not an *instance attribute*. That is, the following would be valid:

```py
C.y = 12 # note the upper case C!
```

Comment: There is a class dictionary but no C object dictionary. I know the way you described to change the value of C.y.  But why I get the AttributeError when using slots? It looks like the class attribute y should be changed via the object.

Comment: @MichaelSchäfer I guess because Python blocks all access to instance members other than the ones defined in the slots. Since you accessed `y` through the instance, it won't bubble up to the class level.